# Constructing an explicit isomorphism between two fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, extension-field

Let $f(x)=x^2+x+1\in \mathbb{F}_2[x]$ and $\mathbb{F}_4:= \mathbb{F}_2[x]/(f(x))$. Let $\alpha$ be the element $(01)$ in $\mathbb{F}_4$, $\alpha=x$ in polynomial form.

Show that $\mathbb{F}_4[x]/(x^2+x+\alpha)$ is isomorphic to the field $\mathbb{F}_{16}=\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^4+x^3+1)$ by explicitly constructing an isomorphism between the fields.

Comment: What is $F_16$?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange! Your question could be greatly improved by giving some background, especially letting other users know how you have been approaching the problem and where you are stuck. See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question for more information.